# JPA Insert and Update

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

I am learning EJB3.1 and JPA2

I am doing following things for Insert and Update

INSERT

```
Common com = new Common();
com.setKeyData(keyData);
com.setKeyValue("0001");
em.persist(com);
```

UPDATE

```
Common com = em.find(Common.class, pk);
com.setKeyValue("0002");
```

The above code works but i would like to know if that's all i need to do for inserting and updating.
I saw few posts where they do begin(), commit() etc (probably used in swing app).
As i am new to JPA/ORM i really want to know if the above code is enough for a application with lot of data load, is there anything i am missing or  should i read/learn more about inserting/updating data.

When should i use the EntityManager's close,clear and flush methods, in which scenario is it used.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be fine in most cases. In a lot of EJB development, the lifecycle of transactions will be handled by the container - so there is no need to explicitly mark the beginning of a transaction.

For more fine-grained control you can also use Bean managed transactions, in which you will need to call begin and commit/rollback to manage the lifecycle yourself.

For more detail take a look at:

Container managed: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction3.html
Bean managed: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction4.html

Answer (score 1):

When using EJB with JPA , you need not worry after begining a transaction , commiting them.
All that is done by the underlying Container .
When using EJB , you just need to annotate it with @PersistentContext(name="CustDB")

```
@PersistenceContext(name="PersistentUnitName")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

begin/commit are used for controlling transactions (to ensure [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)) if this isn't done by something else for you (see other posts).

A possible use of a transaction can look like this:

```
EntityManager em = ...
EntityTransaction tx = null;
try {
  tx = em.getTransaction();
  tx.begin();
  // your code that should be executed within the transaction
  tx.commit();
} catch(Exception ex) {
  // roll back if something failed
  if (tx != null && tx.isActive()) {
    tx.rollback();
  }
} finally {
  // make sure em is closed on commit and on rollback
  em.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close `EntityManager` if it is application managed. It means that you created it by yourself (without injection). You should use `begin`,`commit` ... if you want to manage your transaction by youself (`BMT` or Bean Managed Transaction). But usually you will work with `CMT`(Container Managed Transaction) and this methods will not be useful. You can use `flush` anywhere if transaction is currently opened. You can use `clear` method if you want to detach all manged entities from persistence context.

But my answers are very short and I think that [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence) will be useful for you. There are a lot of details in related books too.